# Magento website shows index.php

Tags: magento, url, indexing

I have developed magento [site](https://tumree.com) I just want to remove index.php from URL and I did successfully by adding below code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On<br/>
RewriteBase /<br/>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But the website is visible, when I'm trying hit https://tumree.com/index.php
In SEO perpective, there shouldn't be duplicate in URL. The two URLs are indexing and its not good.

Please help me to fix the issue...